# Laravel - How to pass array to dynamic blade component? Cannot use object of type Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent as array

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9, dynamic-components

I've got a dynamic component which I am trying to pass an array of data to like:

```
<x-dynamic-component
            :component="$component['component']"
            :data="$component"
        />
```

However when I try and access $data from within my component blade view. $data is not an array, its and instance of Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent:

```
Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent {#1564 ▼ // resources/views/components/page-builder/test-one.blade.php
  #except: []
  +componentName: "dynamic-component"
  +attributes: Illuminate\View\ComponentAttributeBag {#1567 ▼
    #attributes: array:1 [▼
      "data" => Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent {#1564}
    ]
  }
  +component: "page-builder.test-one"
}
```

I've also tried:

```
    <x-dynamic-component
        :component="$component['component']"
        data="{{$component}}"
    />
```

but then I recieve

> htmlspecialchars(): Argument #1 ($string) must be of type string, Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent given.

Any help on how I can pass an array of data to the view and how to access it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation I've managed to resolve the issue thanks to rodrigo.pedra answer at https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/dynamic-blade

```
        @php
            $data =  \Illuminate\Support\Arr::get($component, 'data');
            dump($component['data']);
            dump($data);
        @endphp

        <x-dynamic-component
            :component="$component['component']"
            :props="$data"
        />
```

Even though $component['data'] and data are the same and both arrays, it appears that the blade component doesn't like passing through the array when accessing the array from the index :/

so setting the php like below works:

```
$data = $component['data']
```

or just passing $component into :props throws an error :/

I hope this helps someone :)